# Django mostrando erro 500 ao invés de mostrar erro 404

Tags: django

Meu arquivo `views.py`:

```
def handler404(request):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)

def handler500(request):
    return render(request, '500.html', status=500)
```

Meu arquivo `urls.py`:

```
handler404 = general_views.handler404
handler500 = general_views.handler500

urlpatterns = [
    (...)
]
```

Quando tento acessar no browser alguma URL que não existe no meu `urlpatterns` do arquivo `urls.py`, renderiza sempre a tela de erro 500 ao invés de renderizar a tela de erro 404.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [documentação Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#handler404), na parte que trata das páginas de erro personalizadas, é obrigatório que a view customizada do erro 404 aceite dois parâmetros: o `request` e o `exception`.

A omissão o parâmetro `exception` na view `handler404` estava causando um erro e por isso sempre era mostrado erro 500 (erro interno no servidor). Também de acordo com a documentação, a view `handler500` possui apenas um parâmetro mesmo.

O código correto para o arquivo `view.py` é:

```
def handler404(request, exception):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)

def handler500(request):
    return render(request, '500.html', status=500)
```